# DynamoDB attribute_exists doesn't work

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Banging my head for a couple hours with this and I can't understand why it's not working

I have a DynamoDBv2 table (top level attributes are shown as separate columns) with items like these:

```
{
    gateway: 'gateway1',
    device_id: '2',
    state: { temperature: 20, humidity: 30, pressure: 101049 },
    timestamp: 1498331237261
},
{
    gateway: 'gateway1',
    device_id: '2',
    state: { temperature: 20, humidity: 30, pressure: 101049, lat: 2, long: 1 },
    timestamp: 1498331237262
}
```

Primary partition key: `device_id` (String)

Primary sort key: `timestamp` (Number)

I'm trying to get the latest item for a certain device that has the attributes `lat` and `long`.

```
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const id = 2;
const params = {
    TableName: 'device_telemetry',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'device_id = :id',
    ProjectionExpression: '#s, #lat, #lng, #ts',
    FilterExpression: 'attribute_exists(#lat) AND attribute_exists(#lng)',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#s': 'state',
        '#lat': 'state.lat',
        '#lng': 'state.long',
        '#ts': 'timestamp'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':id': id.toString()
    },
    ScanIndexForward: false,
        Limit: 1
    };

    const onResult = (res) => {
        console.info('devices res for: ', id, res);
    };

    console.info('query: ', params);
    docClient.query(params).promise().then(onResult);
```

If I use `attribute_exists(#s)`, then it works, but for `#lat` or `#long` it doesn't

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You can not directly access nested attributes. You should declare in this format

```
 ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#s': 'state',
    '#lat': 'lat',
    '#lng': 'long',
    '#ts': 'timestamp'
},
```

and access the attributes  in following way:

```
FilterExpression: 'attribute_exists(#s.#lat) AND attribute_exists(#s.#lng)',
```

Comment: Could please explain if the attribute_exists checks whether the #s.#lat attribute key exists or whether the #s.#lat attribute value exists? because i am confused, as there are examples where that expression checks for the exact value of the PK is present in the table or not.

Comment: attribute_exists checks if the key was explicitly set. Thus, if no explicit value is set for key, key will not abe present in tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I was mixing item attributes with the attributes of the map value of `state`.
It was confusing when I was looking at the generated result.

Sorry for the noise.